# Start Neo4j 3.0.0 server from python on Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, neo4j

I wrote an app using Neo4j 3.0.0 on Windows 7. I'd like to add to it a feature that would start a local neo4j server if it is not running.

Normally to manage neo4j I use the scripts provided with the distribution. In this case I would just use: `.\neo4j.bat install-service | start | stop | status | uninstall-service`. How to make these scripts run from within python 2.7?

I tried both: `os.system(<command>)` and `subprocess.call(<command>, shell=True|False)` methods with different variants of the command (using `start`, `start-service`, `start-process` with and without `runAs`) but nothing works. I probably make some stupid mistakes in the command.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made some mistakes in path quotations. If anybody is interested in the answer here's a simple example of what worked for me:

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.call("powershell Start-Process C:/neo4j/bin/neo4j.bat start -verb runAs")
```